# Finding the critical points of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the critical points of the function

$$(x,y,z)\stackrel{f}{\to}yx^2 + zy^3 + z + 2yx - zy - z.$$

I've taken the partial derivatives:

1. $f_x=2yx + 2y$,
2. $f_y=x^2 + 3zy^2 + 2z$,
3. $f_z=y^3 + 1 - 2y - 1$.

I've started making the partial derivative equations equal to $0$

Comment: Try factoring $2zy-2z=0$.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually got to that step, have added it in now. But in terms of doing the simultaneous equations/another approach I am lost here

Comment: $2z(y-1)$ is $0$ if either $z=0$ or $y=1$. You then need to check these cases. So Case 1: $x=-1$ and $z=0$, Case 2: $x=-1$ and $y=1$. For each case substitute values into the final equation.

Comment: what does the $x,y,z=$ mean, is it $f(x,y,z)=$ and find the critical points of $f$ ?

Comment: $f_y$ and $f_z$ are not quite right for the given $f$. It's also a bit odd for a given function to contain canceling terms ($z$ and $-z$), are you sure $f$ is correct?